# Как решить простое уравнение Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, уравнения

Пишу систему ГДЗ. Нужно, чтобы пользователь ввёл уравнение (*с 1 неизвестным x*), а программа вывела **решение** и **ответ**. Пытался делать через срезы, но это очень долго.

Примеры:

1)*Ввод:*

`x+226=300`

*Вывод:*

```
x=300-226
x=74
```

2)*Ввод:*

```
x+22-(33+44)=0
```

*Вывод:*

```
x+22-77=0
x+22=0+77
x+22=77
x=77-22
x=55
```

Comment: а x может умножаться на число?

Comment: самый надежный способ, но это забивание микроскопом гвоздей - закинуть запрос в wolfram (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2B22-%2833%2B44%29%3D0) и распарсить ответ, выбрал PlaneText

Comment: @Zhihar Да, может

Comment: А если парсить, скиньте, пожалуйста, код ;) У меня нет опыта (не умею, короче)

Comment: тут можно более изящное решение придумать на основе словаря с "магическими" методами.

Comment: да я тоже пока таким не занимался, только в планах, ну тогда данный путь вам не подходит

Comment: если x - целое и небольшое, то можно через перебор и `eval` сделать иначе надо писать код по раскрытию скобок и умножению на скобки и последовательно уменьшать кол-во компонент в вашем уравнении

Comment: какие операции могут быть в уравнении? Вообще любые, вплоть до факториалов и логарифмов? Может даже диф. уры?))

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич нет, пока только 4 арифметических)))) +скобки

Comment: но без деления на x?

Comment: Ну с `eval` у меня ещё вначале идея была...

Comment: хотя если неточно, то можно написать код для решения любых уравнений через eval и метод Ньютона

Comment: Если парсить, то словарь и магические методы арифметических операций https://habr.com/ru/post/186608/

Comment: Спасибо) Пока ищем простыми методами, если не найдём, буду парсить

Comment: Там не сложный парсер. Стек + словарик. Строк в 50 максимум выйдет.

Comment: Да?! Ну тогда попробую обязательно!!! Спасибо!

Comment: я думал, больше 200 строк будет  =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если нужен только результат, т.е. найти значение переменной `x`, но не показывать шаги решения, то это легко делается при помощи модуля [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html):

```
from sympy import symbols, solve, parse_expr, simplify
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import standard_transformations, implicit_multiplication_application

transformations = (standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,))

formula = "x(4x+22)-(3x+44)^2=0"

def map_operations(formula_str):
    return formula_str.replace("^", "**").replace("=", "-")

f = parse_expr(map_operations(formula), transformations=transformations)
roots = solve(f) # <-- вернуть все корни уравнения в виде списка
print(roots)
```

вывод:

```
[-121/5 - 11*sqrt(41)/5, -121/5 + 11*sqrt(41)/5]
```

также модуль SymPy умеет аналитически упрощать выражения:

```
In [7]: simplify(f)
Out[7]: -5*x**2 - 242*x - 1936

In [8]: simplify(parse_expr("(x-1) * (x+1)"))
Out[8]: x**2 - 1
```

Comment: А где выводится значение x?

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия3-8, `solve(f)` вернет все корни уравнения в виде списка. Даже если корень один - `solve(f)` вернет список

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас опробую)

Comment: Не работает, просто консоль без всего

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия3-8, напечатайте вывод: `print(solve(f))` из примера в ответе. PS не думал, что вам нужно такие "азы" объяснять...

Comment: спасибо, забыл заглянуть в код) времени не было, просто скопировал